# How can I distribute my windows phone 7 app to a specific community?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I want to make available my windows phone 7 app to a specific community like my collegues in office.
And the app would be accessing internal webservices which is available only in intranet. I am not sure about how the current Windows Phone 7 app certification would test this kind app and marketplace would support this kind of app distribution.

Please let me know.

Comment: There's been talk of private sections of the Marketplace, specifically for cases like yours. I'm not sure though if this feature is live yet. You'll probably need an enterprise contract with the Marketplace.

Comment: It's been live for a good months time.

Comment: @Claus: how about a link or reference?

Comment: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/07/20/windows-phone-developers-get-new-app-hub-features-mango-app-submission-just-one-month-away.aspx , but anyone with a developer account could just login on the AppHub, the changes are fairly visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now publish an app as "Hidden" and it will not show up in Marketplace searches.  Users have to have a link to install the app.

As far as functionality that is only going to work when connected to your intranet, make sure you handle errors that would occur outside the intranet, and add a note to testers when you submit the app, letting them know that it will be published as hidden for a limited audience, and that some (or even all) of the functionality will not work outside the intranet environment.  This is one of the reasons that they implemented the hidden publish option.

Comment: And make sure you do some authentication before you let the user of the app access the intranet. Not sure how you are planning to setup certain things, but a hidden app can alsways be installed by somebody outside your company, for instance, the e-mail with the hidden link could be forwarded to somebody outside the company.

Comment: Thanks, invalidusername - I have not used hidden publish, so I wasn't aware that there was no restriction in place as to who is allowed to install, like there is for the beta.